# Cancellation of integrals

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Suppose we have two continuous functions $f,g: \mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$

Then, suppose $$\forall a,b \in \mathbb{R:}\int\limits_{a}^{b} f(x)dx = \int\limits_{a}^{b} g(x)dx$$

Can we conclude that $f =g$?

If not, under what conditions can we conclude that $f=g$?

If yes, can you provide a proof and is the same result possible with weaker assumptions?

Can we generalise this to other kinds of integrals (line integrals, surface integrals, double integrals, ...)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it. This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**hint**

let $a\in \mathbb R $.

$f ,g$ continuous at  $\mathbb R\;\;\implies $

$$F:x\mapsto \int_a^x f (t)dt $$
$$=G (x)=\int_a^x g (t)dt$$
differentiable at $\mathbb R\;$ and

$$F'(x)=G'(x)=f (x) =g (x)$$

$$\implies f=g $$

Comment: More an answer than a hint really. A good one nonetheless.

Comment: A good hint but the question is broader than this.

Answer (score -3):

Take f and g to be **any** two odd functions.  Then $\int_{-a}^a f(x)dx= \int_{-a}^b g(x)dx= 0$.

In general just the fact that the integral between two fixed points of two functions are the same number tells us nothing about the relationship between the two functions.  If $\int_a^b f(x)dx= \int_a^b g(x)dx$ for **all** a and b, **then** f(x)= g(x) for all x.

Comment: I am aware that for single numbers we cannot conclude anything. That's why I mentioned in the question that it must hold for all a,b.

Comment: The first part of your answer is irrelevant for the question, and the last sentence just restates the question as fact without proof.